# Ошибка при установке browser-sync

Tags: gulp, browsers, npm

При установке `npm install browser-sync`

Выдает ошибку `npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6`

Почему, что за ошибка и как решить эту проблему?!

Answer (score 1):

как подсказывают [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27135672/4827341), зависимый пакет не может установиться. попробуйте установить его отдельно:

```
npm install fsevents
```

Comment: вообще ERR полезли 

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
...
npm ERR! argv "c:/..."
npm ERR! node

Comment: а у вас операционная система *ms/windows*?

Comment: да, все было нормально, уже пару проектов точно так же все делал создавал и все работало, а сейчас все полетело не понятно по какой причине

Comment: возможно, разработчики что-то поломали в новой версии. попробуйте устанавливать [более ранние версии](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Comment: тоже так уже подумал, но стоят как раз новые самые, вот может быть наоборот старые попробовать)))
Вот уже попробовал самое элементарное, минификатор запустить - без ошибок и warn но не работает ... раньше работало